# rails validation of presence not failing on nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I want to make sure an attibute exists, but it seems to still slip thru and I'm not sure how better to check for it.

This should work, but doesn't.  It's a attr_accessor and not a real attribute if that makes a difference.

```
validates_presence_of :confirmed, :rooms

{"commit"=>"Make Booking",
 "place_id"=>"the-kosmonaut",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Tkd9bfGqYFfYUv0n/Kqp6psXHjLU7CmX+D4UnCWMiMk=",
 "utf8"=>"âœ“",
 "booking"=>{"place_id"=>"6933",
 "bookdate"=>"2010-11-22",
 "rooms"=>[{}],
 "no_days"=>"2"}}
```

Not sure why my form_for returns a blank hash in an array...

```
<% form_for :booking, :url => place_bookings_path(@place) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :bookdate, { :value => user_cart.getDate } %>
<%= f.hidden_field :no_days, { :value => user_cart.getDays } %>

<% for room in pricing_table(@place.rooms,@valid_dates) %>

  <%= select_tag("booking[rooms][][#{room.id}]", available_beds(room)) %>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Override `validate` method and write your custom validation check there. Something like

```
def validate
  if rooms.blank? || rooms.first.blank? # first because it seems to be an array that holds only one Hash.
    errors.add_to_base "Rooms can't be blank."
  end
end
```

By the way, why is `rooms` structured to be an array that holds a single hash? For a more sensible solution, you might want to explain that.

Comment: I am not sure why it returns a blank hash... I'll update my question with the form details, maybe you can tell me.

Comment: actually that didn't work for some reason, though it is plural, rooms.blank? || rooms.first.blank?

Comment: You might want to explain why the hash in the array. The key is to write your own validate method and have you own logic determine whether there should be validation error or not.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Chirantan's answer, isn't rooms a child of the booking hash? So shouldn't it be:

```
def validate
  if booking[:rooms].blank? || booking[:rooms].first.blank? 
    errors.add_to_base "Rooms can't be blank."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

validates_presence_of checks whether a field is blank. The validation would fail if your rooms array was empty (  set to []   ), but since your array contains a hash it is not empty, so the validation does not fail.

To demonstrate, try this from the console:

```
a = []
a.empty?
```

This will return true.

```
a = [{}]
a.empty?
```

Returns false.

Comment: i kinda figured that, but how do I make a validation to check for a blank hash inside an array?

Comment: You can create a custom validator for your field using several techniques - see API documentation on 'validates' for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing a dimension from your array:

```
<%= select_tag("booking[rooms][#{room.id}]", available_beds(room)) %>
```

instead of

```
<%= select_tag("booking[rooms][][#{room.id}]", available_beds(room)) %>
```

Comment: The extra dimension is needed to push them all into one big array, as I'm storing the room_id and then the value or number of people in the room.  This was the only way I could get this to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205974/rails-attr-accessor-complex-select-array